# setCustomValidity is not a method of [object HTMLInputElement] In IE

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am using http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html Webshims Lib to do the form validations

It is working fine on Firefox, chrome, safari.

In IE it is throwing the error

```
 setCustomValidity is not a method of [object HTMLInputElement].
```

This is first time I am using webshims Lib, completely clueless about the error.

Answer (score -1):

Finally Figured out.

Some plugin files are missed.